# Numpy - create a random array from the range (1-100)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, databricks

I've got a question saying that "Create an 8×8 array with random natural values from the range (1-100) on the diagonal. Other values should be 0. Hint: You can use numpy's 'eye' function."

I know for random array in numpy I need to use the following code

```
P = np.random.rand(8,8)
print(P)
```

But I don't know how I can choose the range for it. I read that I can use random.radiant, but that one is not working (I am writing my code on databrick). I appreciate it if you could help me to figure out what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two ways:

```
import numpy as np

N = 8
rand_vals = np.random.randint(1, 101, size=N)

# I would go with:
out = np.diag(rand_vals)

# If you insist on using eye:
out = np.eye(N) * rand_vals
```

You can use `np.random.rand` to simulate `np.random.randint` between 1-100 like so:

```
rand_vals = np.floor(np.random.rand(N) * 100) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will do exactly what you are asking for. first create zero matrix. then create random numbers. then put them in dioganals. using np functions will be fastest.

```
import numpy as np
a=np.zeros((8,8))
r=np.random.randint(1, 101, size=8)
np.fill_diagonal(a,r)
```